# Python compare two lists, if words match add to another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, compare

Im trying to compare 'words' with 'if_contains', when they match they should be added into save list. Expected output - ['one', 'two eight nine']. The output im getting - `['one']`

```
if_contains = ['one', 'two', 'three']
save = []
words = ['one', 'five', 'six', 'two eight nine']

for word in words:
    if word in if_contains:
        save.append(words)

print(save)
```

Comment: Typo: `save.append(word)`

Comment: While this works I don't think it will match 'two eight nine' with 'two'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look.
There was mistake with words and you need to use nested loop with that.

```
if_contains = ['one', 'two', 'three']
save = []
words = ['one', 'five', 'six', 'two eight nine']

for if_c in if_contains:
    for word in words:
        if if_c in word:
            save.append(word)

print(save)
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is that you save the whole words list instead of single elements. You probably wanted to do

```
save.append(word)
```

instead of

```
save.append(words)
```

Secondly, if you want to save `two eight nine` as matching with the `if_contains` list, then instead of performing `if word in if_contains`, you should ask whether for any element of `if_contains`, this element is in `word` (which isn't the best choice for the variable name as it represents a few words occasionally). Final solution:

```
if_contains = ['one', 'two', 'three']
save = []
words = ['one', 'five', 'six', 'two eight nine']

for word in words:
    for el in if_contains:
        if el in word:
            save.append(word)

print(save)
```

Comment: my mistake, but if i put in word, the output is ['one']
it still doesnt add the 'two eight nine'

Answer (score 0):

You're appending the whole list to the `save` list variable. Use `save.append(word)` instead of `save.append(words)`

```
if_contains = ['one', 'two', 'three']
save = []
words = ['one', 'five', 'six', 'two eight nine']

for word in words:
    if word in if_contains:
        save.append(word)

print(save)
```

Comment: Yes, im sorry didnt see that, just edited it, but it still doesnt add the 'two eight nine' not sure why

Answer (score 0):

Use `list comprehension`

```
if_contains = ['one', 'two', 'three']
save = []
words = ['one', 'five', 'six', 'two eight nine']

[word for word in words if word in if_contains]
```

```
['one']
```

Comment: Rather `[word for word in words for c in if_contains if c in word]`

Answer (score 0):

Ehy,
but in case I want to get just the whole-word and not a substring?

```
if_contains = ['napoli', 'salvini', 'one']
save = []
words = ['napoli', 'pierosalvini', 'stellone', 'pietrone']

for word in words:
    for el in if_contains:
        if el in word:
            save.append(word)

print(save)
```

In this case I've all the wods with the substrings in them.
But I'd like to have just napoli, because it's 100% matched.
All the characters have to be the same.

Thanks

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30704701)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to solve:

```
p_calcio01=open('parole_calcio.txt')
p_calcio = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in p_calcio01]

for row in frame:
    for word in p_calcio:
        for word1 in frame["Cleaned Text into list"]: #words list in a dataframe
            if word1 in word:
                 frame["Cluster"] = "Calcio"
frame
```

The parole_calcio.txt is  a simple word(s) list every row.
Dataframe is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUMPe.png)

`frame["Cluster"]` is a new Column